# Automatic Detection/Parsing of tables in Python

Tags: parsing, yacc, bnf, marpa

I have to parse a lot of UNIX CLI output, most of the time, the output is a table, but they always differ in number of columns/format...etc, I have to keep modifying my parsing code for every command. TxtFSM makes life easy but i still have to write the template.

I would like to write a script that will automatically detect the CLI output and when it detects a table, it would parse it. As a newbie to the world of Parsing, I wonder How hard/complicated could that be ? If anyone have seen similar efforts/projects before ?

I always get confused with advanced parsing topics like BNF, YACC...etc

Thanks

Comment: Would you give an example CLI output and the result expected from the parser?

Comment: I want to automatically detect tables, parse them to a python list. any examples would work, output of ls, df...etc any table

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can parse `df` output into table using perl and [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2)

script (`~` denotes lexical rules):

```perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;

use Marpa::R2;

my $g = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new( { source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),

    :default ::= action => [ name, value]
    lexeme default = action => [ name, value] latm => 1

        table       ::= (header [\n]) rows
        header      ~ 'Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on'
        rows        ::= row+ separator => [\n]
        row         ::= fs size used avail use_percent mounted_on

        fs          ~ [A-Z] ':'
        size        ~ digits 'G'
        used        ~ digits 'G'
        avail       ~ digits 'G'
        use_percent ~ digits '%'
        mounted_on  ~ [/\w]+

        digits ~ [\d\.]+

    :discard ~ whitespace
    whitespace ~ [\s]+

END_OF_SOURCE
} );

my $input = <<EOI;
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
C:              101G   90G   11G  90% /cygdrive/c
D:              366G  230G  137G  63% /cygdrive/d
E:               38G  9.6G   28G  26% /cygdrive/e
EOI

say Dumper $g->parse( \$input, { trace_terminals => 0 } ); exit;
```

output:

```
\[
        'table',
        [
            'rows',
            [
                'row',
                [
                    'fs',
                    'C:'
                ],
                [
                    'size',
                    '101G'
                ],
                [
                    'used',
                    '90G'
                ],
                [
                    'avail',
                    '11G'
                ],
                [
                    'use_percent',
                    '90%'
                ],
                [
                    'mounted_on',
                    '/cygdrive/c'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'row',
                [
                    'fs',
                    'D:'
                ],
                [
                    'size',
                    '366G'
                ],
                [
                    'used',
                    '230G'
                ],
                [
                    'avail',
                    '137G'
                ],
                [
                    'use_percent',
                    '63%'
                ],
                [
                    'mounted_on',
                    '/cygdrive/d'
                ]
            ],
            [
                'row',
                [
                    'fs',
                    'E:'
                ],
                [
                    'size',
                    '38G'
                ],
                [
                    'used',
                    '9.6G'
                ],
                [
                    'avail',
                    '28G'
                ],
                [
                    'use_percent',
                    '26%'
                ],
                [
                    'mounted_on',
                    '/cygdrive/e'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks @rns I would like to do the parsing "automatically" without having to write specific parsing code for each separate output. 

So one code only to detect that tables in any command like df, ls...etc and automagically parse it.

Just like how copying the table into an excel sheet, automatically parses it into cells.

Comment: Well, a good old @cells = split /\s+/, $row (or another suitable regex) would serve you better then.

Comment: I suppose this is perl, can u pls explain this code.

Comment: it converts a string into array by stripping out separators (whitespaces -- /\s+/ -- in this case). python has split method for any string -- http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-python